# How to allow users to move button horizontally and table view vertically?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have table view with button. I have added UIPanGestureRecognizer to button to allow user to move button horizontally. But then vertical scroll of whole table view does not work now when user touches the button. If I don't use gesturerecognizer, vertical scroll works ok. How to allow users to move button horizontally and table view vertically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you intercept the gesture recoginition, you are blocking the `UITableView` to get notified about the gesture event. To deal with this, in the same place (method) that you recognize a gesture, do a comparison. If it is a horizontal gensture (e.g. horizontal pan), do whatever you want to do, otherwise, pass it along the chain, so that the table view gets a chance to respond to it.

**EDIT**

It depends what methods you have, and what methods you have overriden. Once you recognized the touch event. Here is an example:

> ```
> -(void)respondToEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
>        if (event == horizontalPan)
>           [self handleEvent:event];
>        else
>           [super respondToEvent:event];
> }
> ```

You should call the same method on the next responder (or super).

References:

1. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW5
2. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIResponder
3. http://books.google.com/books?id=rk1EEL4WpFEC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA530#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: How to pass it along the chain?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I want to do it in gesturerecognizers method. - (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture. I want to skip execution of that method and pass execution to next view.

Comment: Well, one way or another, you eventually need to pass it to the super if you want the tableview handle the event, otherwise, there is no way for the tableview to get notified of that event. You are blocking it from travelling along the chain. You can implement your own methods, but once you realized it is not the gesture you are interested in, you need to pass it along.